# T test or a different analysis? advice

Tags: anova, t-test

I want to make sure i get the right analysis.

I have taken chemical measurements of soil at two grasslands at two depths. For example soil PH.

So one with chemical treatment and one without at two different depths (10cm and 50 cm).

What is an appropriate analysis. I was thinking just a T test?

best Wishes

Comment: What is your research question?

Comment: Hi, I just wat to see if there is any difference between the treatments and the depths.

Comment: "Any difference" is too vague. A t-test compares means. Is that what you want? Or do you want to test medians? Or maybe whole distributions? And it makes some assumptions.  Also, there is always going to be *some* difference. Maybe you don't want a test?  Also, if the samples are stacked (one below the other) then you will want some kind of paired analysis.  Also, do you have any covariates?

Answer (score 1):

A t-test compares means. But you have two independent variables (depth and treatment) so a t-test can't be right. You probably want some form of regression, but it might have to be a multilevel model, if the samples are "stacked" that is, if one is right over the other.

And you might want to add other covariates -- I know little about soil, but maybe the moisture content or the temperature or stuff like that.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a difference between PH, Redox, temperature and conductivity at different depths and at different treatments. I am not sure what test is appropriate.

Comment: Which test is appropriate depends on the issues I raised.